# Update user when node is created

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm new in Drupal 8 and I need to update the user when a *node* of a specific content type is created or updated. I found `hook_entity_create` but this hook acts when creating a new *entity*. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're 3 main hooks you can ustilise here:

1. **hook_entity_insert:** for when an entity is actually created
2. **hook_entity_update:** for when an entity is updated
3. **hook_entity_delete:** for when an entity is deleted

***Note: Beware that this hook will be called on any entity so unless you intend to make whatever operation you're performing run on every entity, do something like this:***

```
function yourmudolename_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity instanceof \Path\to\your\EntityInterface){
     // Your code here
  }
}
```

Or better still use the entity type hook insead.

1. hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert
2. hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update
3. hook_ENTITY_TYPE_delete

See here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.5.x for details.